# How to set values to a environment variable of List type for a Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-functions

For single-valued variable, I can set something like this:

```
Option__Property=a
```

But what if the variable is a list of string? I tried the following two approaches, none of them work:

```
Option__Property__0=a
Option__Property__1=b
```

or:

```
Option__Property__0__=a
Option__Property__1__=b
```

Only thing it was close is this:

```
Option__Property__=a
```

But I cannot set multiple values for it.
Any idea?

Comment: If the settings are like: `{ "Option": { "Property": ["a"] } }`, then I think you should be able to override the array value with: `Option__Property__0` as the key.

Comment: That works only in appsetting.json file, not in the configuration page of Azure Function.

Comment: How did you use the list data in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works in **appsettings.json** not in configuration section. I have reproduced in my environment and below is my trick to solve this issue:

**`For Asp.net core:`**

**`Program.cs:`**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//workaround
var variable = builder.Configuration["option"];
char del = ',';
string[] res = variable.Split(del);
foreach (string item1 in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item1);
}

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**`appsettings.json:`**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "option": "a,b"
}
```

Here, i have used comma and used split, to split it used Split() and use them.

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`In Azure function:`**

**`Function1.cs:`**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FunctionApp66
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
       
            string res = config["option"];
            char del = ',';
            log.LogInformation($"MyVariable: {res}"); 
            string[] res1 = res.Split(del);
            foreach (string item1 in res1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item1);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(res);
        }
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
      "option": "a,b"
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Note:`**

Here, you have to give list as I have given(string with comma ,), dynamic list does not work.